# c++ variadic template friend

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, friend

I can easily create template class that is friend with generic `T` class:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Secret {
private:
    friend T;

    Secret() {}
};
```

I would like to do the same, but with variadic template arguments. I want `MultiSecret` to be friend with each type in `Ts`. Is it possible to do? How can I unpack `Ts`?

```cpp
template <typename... Ts>
class MultiSecret {
private:    
    // How to unpack Ts?

    MultiSecret() {}
};
```

EDIT. `Secret` and `MultiSecret` classes have private constructors. I want to allow only `Ts` to be able to create `MultiSecret`.

Comment: Why do you need `friend` at all? I never use this keyword.

Comment: @MarekR, you may want to look up "passkey" pattern. Having a generic Key class that is a friend of given set of classes would be nice.